# How to find the angle between two tables given 2 points on table 2 and origin on table 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**
How to find the angle between two tables of same dimensions when 2 points on the second table is known with respect to the origin(0,0,0) on the middle of the first table?

**Knowns**
1.origin on the first table(0,0,0)
2.Point 1 on the second table w.r.t the origin on the first table
3.Point 2 on the second table w.r.t the origin on the first table
4.Both known points on table 2 are on a straight line on table 2 which is parallel to the table 2
1. Angle between the two tables

Please help me to solve this problem.It will be very helpful.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: How are the points on the second table specified? (eg by coordinates relative to a similar coordinate system on the second table). How is the first table oriented with respect to the coordinate system you mention (eg is it in the $x,y$ plane with sides parallel to the axes)?

Comment: @Qwerty.
From the two known points i got the equation of a line(and i can assume a 3rd point on the second table to get a equation of a plane).But this plane will be perpendicular to the two planes of the table where i want to find the angle.I am not at all sure how to proceed with this problem...It will be really helpful if you can give an idea or a way to solve this problem

Comment: @almagest The points on the second table is all relative to the origin and coordinate system in the first table. yes  the coordinate system is oriented in  x,y plane

Comment: @nithinpanand We have a coordinate system based on the centre of Table 1. Suppose it has corners $(\pm a,\pm b,0)$ in this coordinate system. Now there are two points in this coordinate system $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ which belong to Table 2. But whereabouts on Table 2 are they? Anywhere? Or are they corners? Anyway, wherever they are you can rotate Table 2 about the line joining them, so I do not see how any angle can be determined.

Comment: @ almagest. Thanks for your reply.i never thought about this silly issue.But i can measure the distance between these two points(these two points are on a straight line parallel to the table 2) and the four corners of table 2.I think then it gives some information about the table 2.